# Does JavaFX 2 not do dirty region optimization?

Tags: windows, animation, javafx-2, frame-rate

The test application I'm using looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mcow.jpg. It has 3 `ImageViews` that are being moved with a `TranslateTransition`, inside of a `Pane` with a clipping mask.

It seems to me that only the region inside the clipping mask should need to be repainted, which is the same size regardless of the window size. However, the FPS drops noticeably (from ~500 fps to ~180 fps) when I maximize my application window (and the animation gets choppy even though the framerate should technically still be high enough).

(Note: I am aware that there is a setting that controls this. It does not seem to make any difference how I set it.)

Does JavaFX 2 not do proper dirty region optimization? Or is this an artifact of my video driver or video card?

Comment: you should check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380323/why-does-my-java-application-run-so-slowly-in-full-screen-mode-and-fine-when-w

Comment: [Create an issue](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com) with your program source asking the JavaFX developers to investigate the performance.