# Windows aero effects and Java fullscreen

Tags: java, windows, fullscreen, smoothing

I have a Windows application designed in java that enters exclusive fullscreen mode when opened. The application runs at 60fps. The thing is, when Windows aero effects are disabled, the application runs smooth; images move smoothly. When aero effects are enabled, the application runs at the same speed but choppy, as if it were 30fps.

Why is Windows aero effects causing this? How can I run the application smooth with aero effects enabled?

Thanks.

Comment: Try the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380323/why-does-my-java-application-run-so-slowly-in-full-screen-mode-and-fine-when-w

Comment: Tried it, but doesn't work. Gonna try different things with the disable 3d thing.

Comment: You can try using the [`trace` option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/2d/flags.html#trace). This will log info about drawing, and can be made to include timestamps, so you can get an idea of where your drawing code is slowing down. This may help you diagnose the problem.